# Bash command to close all detached running programs by GNU screen?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-screen

Is there a single command for `screen` to completely close/quit all running programs in detached mode?

I hope to do this in a bash script without any further input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `screen -X` to send a command to a running screen, so `screen -X quit` should ask the session to terminate and kill all of its windows.

If you have multiple screens running, use `-S` to identify them.

Comment: It is intended to be used in a `bash` script rather than terminal input. I edited the question.

Comment: @All, I'm not sure what the issue is there, `screen -X quit -S $sessionname` will still ask a running screen session to quit, regardless of if the command is given from an interactive shell, or a script. Do you mean you have multiple screen sessions running, and want to close them all?